# Is it possible to load a trained Rasa NLU model and run inference to get embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa

I have trained a `supervised_embeddings` Rasa NLU model using `rasa train nlu`. For my specific use case, I now need to get the embeddings for inputted user messages, and compare the embeddings with those of messages in my NLU training data.

Is it possible to use the Python API to load the trained model, and use it to get the embedding of a string of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered on the [rasa forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-use-a-trained-supervised-embeddings-nlu-pipeline-to-get-the-embedding-of-a-user-inputted-message/24441). For easy reference - pass `only_output_properties=False` to the `interpreter.parse` method:

You can do this from within a python script:

```
from rasa.nlu.model import Interpreter

interpreter = Interpreter.load('models/nlu-xyz/nlu')) ## this should be an extracted model
result = interpreter.parse('hello world',only_output_properties=False)
embeds = result.get("text_sparse_features")
```

Answer (score 0):

@KOB Unfortunately, we don't have an API for it. You can take a look into the code at https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/rasa/nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py#L572 and use `message_embed` as the embedding.
Feel free to ask any further questions.